# Как обрезать блоки с помощью CSS?

Tags: html, css

Вот есть 3 блока, два с верху и один с низу, два верхних обрезают нижний, а линия между ними это border, при наводке на любой блок, фон увеличивается, я никак не могу придумать как обрезать.

[image: Необычный дизайн]

Comment: опишите подробнее, что происходит по наводке, как именно увеличивается фон

Comment: фон(изображение) увеличивается по центру, я пробовал блоки transform:skew наклонять, но это не то, может какие то идее есть...

Comment: на вскидку приходит идея сделать на canvas блоки, и тогда если у блока будет `overflow: hidden` всё будет обрезаться как надо

Comment: Я тоже подумал об этом, пробовал еще skew'ом наклонять блоки, а внутренний блок повернуть обратно, только вот border не выходит... Думал еще clip-path использовать, но тут напрочь можно забыть про поддержку старых браузеров

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPNEex?editors=0100  это я не доделал ещё

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю никак не обрезать.

**html**
для создания нижнего блока в виде ромба, достаточно повернуть прямоугольный или квадратный блок под 45%, при этом родительскому блоку выставить `overflow: hidden`.

```
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Т.к. разворот под 45 градусов, предпалагет разворот и внутренного содержимого под 45, то внут. содержимое нужно развернуть под 45 градусов в обратном направлении.

```
.child {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.child__inner {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**изображение**
Изображения при этом никак особенно обрезать не надо, желательно что бы оно было достаточно большое, для компенсации зума.

**недостатки**
Приходится вручную подгонять координаты ромба и внут. содержимого.

[**Рабочий пример**](http://codepen.io/olegatro/pen/bpXNMg)

Для `html` и `css` используются препроцессоры `jade` и `stylus` соотвественно. Если с ними не знакомы, там в каждом блоке есть кнопка `View Compiled`

Comment: Спасибо большое, даже и не подумал блок повернуть...

Comment: Но ведь должны быть равные углы по 120 градусов, а при повороте нижний получается 90, а два других по 135...

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы правы, как прямоугольник/квадрат не крути, всеравно будет угол в 90 градусов.  Я не обратил внимание на этот момент, когда делал пример. Но ведь идея была неплохая?). Надо пораскинуть мозгами, но обрезка я думаю это крайний вариант. Возможно с `svg` и масками можно что нибудь придумать. Но у меня сейчас крайне мало времени, попробую потом выделить минутку. Спасибо большое что обратили внимание!

Comment: Задачка действительно оказалась не простая, вот поэтому решил поделиться проблемой) Дизайнеры конечно интересные люди, только вот порой они такое напридумают...

Comment: @Olegatro, да про поворот я и сам думал, но решил промолчать из-за угла. Трансформацию же можно применить, чтобы сделать параллелепипед - можно в этом направлении попробовать.Но там надо думать и считать...

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.wrapper{
  width:600px;
  height:500px;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  margin:20px auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.odin{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border-right:2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom:none;
  position:relative;
  top:1px; left:1px;
  background:red;
  
}

.odin_a{
  width:300px;
  height:500px;
  background:url(http://alleya-mebeli.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bianka.jpg);
  background-size:300px 500px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  z-index:98;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:.5s;
  border-right:2px solid #fff;
}
.odin_a:hover{
  background-size:400px 600px;
  background-position:-30px -50px;
}
.dva{
  width:300px;
  height:500px;
   border-left:2px solid #fff; background:url(http://www.rehabmedical.ru/images/sensroom/photogallery/Spb1.jpg);
  background-size:300px 500px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  transition:.5s;
  border:2px solid #fff;
}
.dva:hover{
  background-size:750px 900px;
  background-position:-40px -40px;
}
.try{
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  border-top:2px solid #fff;
  border-right:2px solid #fff;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-300px;
  top:123px;
  z-index:100;
  background:blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.try_b{
  width:130%;
  height:130%;
  background:url(http://www.news-ontime.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/detskaya-komnata-45.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  margin:-150px 90px;
  transition:all .5s;
}
.try_b:hover{
  background-size:120% 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="odin"> 
  <div class="odin_a"></div>
</div>
<div class="dva"> 
  <div class="dva_a"></div>
</div>
<div class="try"> 
   <div class="try_b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не могу только один блок сделать - самый нижний , transition, уважаемая публика надеюсь поможет

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPNEex?editors=1100  доделал ! пример

Comment: я там накосорезил - в общем лишние блоки вкрутил , можно сократить

Comment: под моим решением, комментатор отметил момент про одинаковый угол в 120 градусов )

Comment: Зачем вы ещё раз написали решение @Olegatro? или думаете что есть поставить другие картинки, то не будет заметна реализация через те же самые `transform:rotate(45deg);`?

Comment: Я думаю, автор просто не видел моего решения, я уже эксперементирую с svg и маской, мне осталось решить проблему зума. Но использовать треугольник в качестве маски для изображения вполне возможно.

Comment: Видел, дело в другом что, у меня не фиксированная ширина... width:100% и height: 100% и сделать еще и адаптивным...

Comment: но вы поймите что hover нету в мобильной версии , точнее все мобильные средства не понимают hover , так что это ни реально

Comment: Все нормально, в мобильной версии это 3 блока будут квадратными. И я использую Mobile Detect для обнаружения устройства

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно использовать clip-path

```css
.container{
 width:1000px;
 height:800px;
 margin:0 auto;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.left, .right, .bottom {
 transition:linear 200ms;
 float:left;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1;
 background:#FFF;
}
.left .bg, .right .bg, .bottom .bg {
 transition:linear 200ms;
 position:absolute;
}
.left {
 height:800px;
 width:800px;
 left:-300px;
 top:0;
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 560px, 300px 100%, 0 100%);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 560px, 300px 100%, 0 100%);
}
.left .bg {
 width:798px;
 height:800px;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 background:url(https://www.firestock.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/abstract-rings-background-700x524.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
 background-size:cover;
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 558px, 300px 100%, 0 100%);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 558px, 296px 100%, 0 100%);
}
.right {
 height:800px;
 width:800px;
 top:0;
 right:-299px;
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 500px 100%, 0 560px);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 500px 100%, 0 560px);
}
.right .bg {
 width:798px;
 height:800px;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 background:url(https://www.firestock.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Dollarphotoclub-65301126-light-700x466.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
 background-size:cover;
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 500px 100%, 0 560px);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 504px 100%, 0 558px);
}
.bottom {
 height:540px;
 width:1000px;
 left:0;
 bottom:-298px;
 clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 240px, 50% 0, 100% 240px, 100% 100%);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 240px, 50% 0, 100% 240px, 100% 100%);
}
.bottom .bg {
 height:539px;
 width:100%;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 background:url(http://www.sunhome.ru/UsersGallery/wallpapers/233/goluboi-fon-oboi.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
 background-size:cover;
 clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 242px, 50% 2px, 100% 242px, 100% 100%);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 242px, 50% 2px, 100% 242px, 100% 100%);
}
.left:hover {
 z-index:2;
 left:0;
}
.right:hover {
 z-index:2;
 right:0;
}
.bottom:hover {
 z-index:2;
 bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">
  <div class="bg"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  <div class="bg"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="bottom">
  <div class="bg"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а вас не смущает то, как себя ведут изображения при наведении? посмотрите примеры ниже, как там работает наведение. Да и автор в комментариях сразу написал: "Думал еще clip-path использовать, но тут напрочь можно забыть про поддержку старых браузеров"

Comment: В принципе идея тоже интересная), но это не то что нужно... Пока что clip-path лучше вообще не использовать

Comment: clip-path не кроссбраузерно , я тоже так хотел сделать